# How do I suppress warnings in Eclipse for PHP?

Tags: php, eclipse, warnings, suppress-warnings

In Eclipse, I'm getting warnings for not having a start tag (`<div>`) because the start tag is in another file.  How do I suppress this warning to keep it out of my "Problems" window?

I know in Java I could do @SuppressWarning, but I don't know how for php.  I assume that there is, based on the availability of php type hinting in Eclipse, but maybe it isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also set this on a per project base. Go to

```
Project -> Properties -> Validation
```

and modify your settings as you like. You can suppress a lot of warnings, especially HTML -> Document Type -> Invalid Location!

Comment: That's more like it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window > Preferences. Under Web > HTML Files > Validation you'll find "Missing start tag:" and "Missing end tag:" [image]

Answer (score 1):

window->preferences->validation->suspend all validators

will also make eclipse way faster :)

Comment: Followup Q: Will that disable PHP validation as well?

Comment: maybe window->preferences->general->editors->structured etxt editors->Appearance, uncheck report problems as you type? or even there is a separate setting in your php editor. ie pdt

Comment: I still want it to detect error and warnings.  I just want to suppress this particular one.  Like I mentioned, Java annotations allow you to to ignore a particular error, and the IDE can pick up on those.  Perhaps there is no PHP equivalent?